# Loop to identify data location in a Dataframe, and populate to new Dataframe (R)

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

So I have a dataframe of user IDs as columns with rows (corresponding to period intervals) with binary variables (where an event happened) like this:

```
date Id1 Id2 id3 id4 id5

row1  1   0   0   1   0
row2  0   0   1   1   0
row3  0   1   0   0   1
row4  1   1   0   0   0
row5  0   0   1   1   1  
...
```

I am trying to build a loop that runs through each row of each column which identifies any cell with a 1 and populates a new data frame with the row number of each occurrence, e.g:

```
  occ. Id1 Id2 id3 id4 id5 
  1    1    3   2   1   3 
  2    4    4   5   2   5
  3                 5    
  4
  5
```

I am pretty lost in how to approach this, if anyone is able to help?

Comment: Your second frame isn't really a frame since you have different lengths of each column. Additionally, your sample frames don't match, can you edit your question to make them representative?

Comment: Best to store in a `list`, e.g. `lapply(df[, -1], function(x) which(x == 1))`

Comment: @r2evans - updated!

Answer (score 0):

You can using `reshape::melt` with `spread` from `tidyverse`

```
reshape::melt(df)%>%filter(.,value==1)%>%group_by(variable)%>%mutate(n=row_number())%>%spread(variable,date)
# A tibble: 3 x 7
  value     n    Id1    Id2    id3    id4    id5
* <int> <int> <fctr> <fctr> <fctr> <fctr> <fctr>
1     1     1   row1   row3   row2   row1   row3
2     1     2   row4   row4   row5   row2   row5
3     1     3     NA     NA     NA   row5     NA
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option using `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
gather(df1, key, val, Id1:id5) %>%
     filter(val != 0) %>% 
     mutate(val = readr::parse_number(date)) %>% 
     spread(key, val) %>% 
     mutate_at(vars(Id1:id5), funs(c(.[!is.na(.)], .[is.na(.)]))) %>%
     rename(occ = date) %>%
     mutate( occ = readr::parse_number(occ))
#   occ Id1 Id2 id3 id4 id5
#1   1   1   3   2   1   3
#2   2   4   4   5   2   5
#3   3  NA  NA  NA   5  NA
#4   4  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
#5   5  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(date = c("row1", "row2", "row3", "row4", "row5"
), Id1 = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), Id2 = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L), 
id3 = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L), id4 = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L), 
id5 = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L)), .Names = c("date", "Id1", "Id2", 
"id3", "id4", "id5"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
 -5L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another slightly different `tidyverse` option:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  gather(id, value, Id1:id5) %>% 
  filter(value != 0) %>% 
  mutate(row = str_replace(date, 'row', '')) %>% 
  select(id, row) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(occ = row_number()) %>% 
  spread(id, row)

# A tibble: 3 x 6
    occ Id1   Id2   id3   id4   id5  
  <int> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1     1 1     3     2     1     3    
2     2 4     4     5     2     5    
3     3 NA    NA    NA    5     NA 


#sample data:

df <- read.table(text='date Id1 Id2 id3 id4 id5
                 row1  1   0   0   1   0
                 row2  0   0   1   1   0
                 row3  0   1   0   0   1
                 row4  1   1   0   0   0
                 row5  0   0   1   1   1', header = TRUE)
```

Comment: @sbha- I get the following response when I run this ( i have chnaged DF for the actual dataframe name), and aam not sure how to resolve it/where the error is coming from:

Error in `[.data.frame`(order_piv_cast, , c(.(occ = 1:N), lapply(.SD,  : 
  unused argument (.SDcols = -"Date")

Comment: I'm not familiar with that error. It looks like it's from a different function call. Are you able to reproduce the output in the answer using the sample data frame? Is it possible the real data frame has different column names or different formats? Capitalization matters - 'Date' vs 'date' would throw an error.

Comment: Apologies, I had omitted converting to data.table. this worked perfectly Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a different approach without reshaping forth and back.

It uses the `which()` function to get the row numbers and collapses each column individually:

```
# get maximum number of rows after collapsing
N <- DT[, Reduce(pmax, lapply(.SD, function(x) sum(x == 1))), .SDcols = -"date"]
DT[, c(.(occ = 1:N), lapply(.SD, function(x) {
  tmp <- which(x == 1)
  c(tmp, rep("", N - length(tmp)))
})), .SDcols = -"date"]
```

> ```
>    occ Id1 Id2 id3 id4 id5
> 1:   1   1   3   2   1   3
> 2:   2   4   4   5   2   5
> 3:   3               5
> ```

#### Data

```
library(data.table)
DT <- fread(
  "date Id1 Id2 id3 id4 id5
row1  1   0   0   1   0
row2  0   0   1   1   0
row3  0   1   0   0   1
row4  1   1   0   0   0
row5  0   0   1   1   1  "
)
```